# jquery.form.js - How to get current form on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I have this markup

```
<form action="..." id="form1" class="foo">...</form>
<form action="..." id="form2" class="foo">...</form>
...
```

and I have this Javascript code

```
$('.foo').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
       // TODO: How do I get the form that triggered this?
       console.log( $(this) );
    }
});
```

As you can see in the Javascript code, I want to get the current form element when
it submits and was succesful. Outputting `$(this)` didn't show me anything that points
to the current form element.

How do I get the current form element inside the success function?

Comment: You want to get Current Form data on submit? Which Programming language u use @ Backend?

Comment: @PratikJoshi Not the data. I want the form element.

Comment: onClick()  you can call a function that set in a variable the ID of the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

You can use 4th parameter

```
 success: function (data, statusText, xhr,  form ) {
```

[**References**](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object)

> success: Callback function to be invoked after the form has been submitted. If a 'success' callback function is provided it is invoked after the response has been returned from the server. It is passed the following arguments:
>
> > 1. responseText or responseXML value (depending on the value of the dataType option).
> > 2. statusText
> > 3. xhr (or the jQuery-wrapped form element if using jQuery < 1.4)
> > 4. jQuery-wrapped form element (or undefined if using jQuery < 1.4)

Answer (score 1):

use :

`context` to pass `this` into success function

check following links : duplicate

[$.ajax context option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097191/ajax-context-option)

[How to pass Object context to jQuery.ajax JSONP callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399997/how-to-pass-object-context-to-jquery-ajax-jsonp-callback)

Answer (score 1):

use [`beforeSubmit`](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) callback:

```
beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options){
    options.context = $form;
}
```

---

Here `$form` is the current form which is getting ajaxified and you can add the context to the `options` of the current `ajaxForm` with `options.context = $form;`. So now this will hold the current form which is getting submitted and you can get the current context.

---

something like this:

```
$('.foo').ajaxForm({
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options){
    options.context = $form;
   },
   success: function (data) {
     // TODO: How do I get the form that triggered this?
     console.log( $(this) );
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change you code into this:

```
var fooForm = $('.foo');
fooForm.ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
       // TODO: How do I get t

       console.log( fooForm);
    }
});
```

You cannot get $(this) because in success callback function,
'this' is point to windows.

In fact you code can be write into this style:

```
var fooForm = $('.foo');
fooForm.ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: successCallback
});
function successCallback(data){
    //'this' point to window : ) 
    console.log( fooForm);

}
```

Hope this would help. :)